# Split dataframe into training and test sets

Tags: r, datetime, testing, split, dataframe

Training / test splits are eleven consecutive days where the first ten are used for training. the eleventh is the test data point. All 526 such periods of consecutive days are used for testing, yielding 526 predictions for each method.

This is the code I wrote:

```
for(i in 1:526){
    test[[i]]<-dataset[i+10,]
    training<-dataset[i:i+9,]
}
```

But I got problem in the second line:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(time = 26, ISE = -0.008776701,  : 
>     replacement has 1 row, data has 107

Comment: `test` is getting every value from 11 to 536. Not what you intended. Also `training` does not have `[[i]]` attached as test does.

Comment: Possibly `ind <- seq(11, 526, by=11); test <- dataset[ind,]; train <- dataset[-ind,]`

Comment: `split(dataset, c(rep("train", 10), "test"))` will give you a list of two data frames named train and test.

Comment: Or perhaps you want nested lists? `day_group = split(dataset, 1:11)`, then `train_test = lapply(day_group, split, f = c(rep("train", 10), "test"))`

Comment: Also you want, at the very least, `i:(i + 9)`, not `i:i + 9`, and as the first comment mentions, an `[[i]]` for the `training` in your loop.